# Avoid that an object created at runtime and place in the same position of another object follow the last, in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A script handle click event on a button. Function's fired with click create a line between two points: Start point and End point. As Start point I put a `GameObject` (lets call it `m_player`) from the inspector. The problem is that the Start point is moving, but I do not want to re-drawn the line from the new Start point to the same End point. So I try to get the position of Star point at the time I need to drawn the line and then drawn the line. To do that I create a new `GameObject` at the position I need (Start point), then drawn the line.
Doing that, nothing change, indeed the new `GameObject` still refer to the old `GameObject`, and then new `GameObject` is moving following the old `GameObject`.

I try different solution, but with the same result.

**First**

GameObject assign from inspector.

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject m_player;
```

Create a copy of the Start point

```
GameObject placeHolder = Instantiate(m_player, m_player.transform.position, m_player.transform.rotation);
placeHolder.SetActive(false);
```

Call the function to drawn the line.

```
getRoute.Initialize(m_gameObjectPOI, placeHolder);
```

**Second**

```
GameObject placeHolder = new GameObject("Place_Holder");
placeHolder.transform.position = m_player.transform.position;
placeHolder.transform.rotation = m_player.transform.rotation;
```

How can I avoid the new `GameObject` to follow `m_player`?

Comment: Why do you create gameobject? Just store start point as Vector3 and use that

Comment: Your second method looks good to me, if you use that as your "copy of the Start point" code, what happens? It doesn't work?

Comment: @mchts I did not find a good way to assign position stored on a vector3 into a Trasform. Anyway, I agree with you, would be better to create a vector3 or a transform, but why with a GameObject did not work?

Comment: @JonasTuemandMøller I have same behaviour with both way. It is like all the time (Update()) the place holder is update with the new Player position, but I do not know why, because I am calling the initialization of Start point with the click event.

Comment: getRoute.Initialize(m_gameObjectPOI, placeHolder); is called in update? placeHolder cannot be a local variable, it will only be available in the local scope (click event). It should be maybe m_placeHolder, do you understand what I'm getting at?

Comment: @JonasTuemandMøller Got it, I am going to try it. 
getRoute.Initialize(m_gameObjectPOI, placeHolder); is called in the click hanlder function.

Comment: And the code labelled Second, that's called in the click handler right? Or some earlier code, Start or similar?